# how to show dojo validation error tool tip?

Tags: dojo

**Question:--**


I am using following HTML code showing error message using tool tip whenever length of Textbook equal to zero,
but i couldn't set my defined message inside tool tip.

```
 <body class="claro">
    <form action="">


    Enter Name:--
    <input type="text" name="firstname" data-dojo-props="" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.TextBox"
    trim="true"  id="firstname" propercase="true">
    <button id="button4" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Button" type="button">Submit
       <script type="dojo/method" event="onClick" args="newValue">
     alert("Value selected is: "+newValue);
            var firstNameId=dijit.byId("firstname").value;
    alert('firstNameId.length:----'+firstNameId.length);

    if(firstNameId.length==0)
    {
    var textBox = dijit.byId("firstname");
    dijit.showTooltip(
        textBox.get("invalidMessage"), 
        textBox.domNode, 
        textBox.get("justMessage"),
        !textBox.isLeftToRight()
    );
    }
    else
    {
    alert('wrong');
    );
    }

    <br>
```

Help me out....

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since you posted this question, but if you still need it, here's an answer.

Dijit/form/TextBox doesn't have a showTooltip method. To show a tooltip you can instead call something like:

```
var textBox = dijit.byId("firstname");

textBox.invalidMessage = "Whatever you want";

Tooltip.show(textBox.get("invalidMessage"), 
             textBox.domNode, textBox.get("tooltipPosition"), 
             !textBox.isLeftToRight());
```

Be sure to include dijit/Tooltip!